# What are these menus called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on an app and I'd like to know what [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuUlC.png) kinda menus are called, the ones with the check marks and such. If anyone could show me any samples and tell me what it's called I'd greatly appreciate it.

[image: PICTURE OF THE APP]

Thanks
- Gretar

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html for the name of the UI elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `UITableView`, with the grouped styling.  The `UITableViewCell` is using the `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.  The other options are as follows:

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

To get the effect in the image, you can set your `UITableView` to grouped, in the xib file.  And use Accessories as you need them.

Extra information:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451